# Homotopy on the unit circle between a continuous function and a constant function.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

> Suppose $f: S^1 \to S^1$ is a continuous function which is homotopic
> to a constant function $g: S^1 \to S^1$, $g(x) = z$ for all $x \in
>  S^1$. Prove there exists $x\in S^1$ such that the arclength between
> $x,f(x)$ is $\pi/6$.

So far, I've thought about using the covering map $p(t) = e^{2\pi it}$. The compositions $\gamma = f \circ p$ and $\delta = g \circ p$ are paths in $S^1$. $\delta$ is a constant path in $S^1$, and $\gamma$ is a closed path since $\gamma(0)=f(p(0))=f(1)=f(p(1))=\gamma(1)$ (we identify $(1,0)$ on $S^1$ with $1+0i$ on the unit circle in the complex plane).

Well, I'm not really sure how to proceed from here (it's not really much to begin with). Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Am I missing something here? The function $g$ is homotopic to itself, but there does not exist $x$ such that the arclength between $x,f(x)$ is $\pi/6$.

Comment: @FranklinPezzutiDyer $x=ze^{-\pi i/6}$ and $g(x)=z$ have angle $\pi/6$. Constant function, not the identity function.

Comment: @NDB Brain fart XD Thank you much

Comment: But the question is about the angle between $x$ and $f(x)$

Comment: What if the desired angle was $0$ -- could you solve that?  A null-homotopic map on $S^1$ having a fixed point is a common and very closely related question.

Comment: The same question has been asked before, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2959109/the-identity-homotopy-on-the-circle-can-create-an-arc-of-any-length).